# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column - but value is not null

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework and in my `serialiazers.py`

```
class MeetingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    meeting_organiser = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Meeting
        fields = '__all__'
```

The `Meeting` model in my `models.py` is like:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    [some fields here...]
    meeting_organiser = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    [more fields here...]
```

However, when I try to do a `save()` to the `Meeting` model I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "meeting_organiser" violates not-null constraint
```

I tried to debug and added in the `serializers.py`:

```
def save(self):
    print(self.validated_data)
```

and in `models.py`:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print(self.meeting_organiser.username)
```

In both cases, the meeting organiser object was not null and it contained the right values.

Comment: Where does the `User` used in `Meeting` comes from ?

Comment: @Linovia, apologies! I did not add this in my question. It comes from the standard django User model and imported like: ``from django.contrib.auth.models import User``.

Comment: just an idea, try setting `null=True` in foreign key.

Comment: @Bhansa, I set `null=True`, then migrated but I am still getting the same error. Then I deleted the migrations, migrated again but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a permission such as [`IsAuthenticated`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated) to make sure the request is authenticated.

Otherwise, you'll get a `AnonymousUser` which translates to `None` and I assume that as this parameter is explicitly given, the model's default doesn't apply.

Comment: In my settings, I have set `REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
` and I have tested that I cannot access the API if I am not authenticated. Besides, in the `models.py` the `print(self.meeting_organiser.username)` returns the right (not null) value.